# Catching Error Message from XP_CMDSHELL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am running the following command:

EXEC @ReturnCode = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmdline

On the Results tab I get 2 lines
 Could not find a part of the path '\server\directory\filename'.
 NULL

How do I capture the first line in an error message?  I tried using a Try Catch block with "SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()" and it doesn't grab it.

The message is not coming from sys.messages.  Where is this error message coming from then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the command shell itself, it is not a SQL Server error

one way to grab the error is

```
declare @cmdline varchar(500),@ReturnCode int
select @cmdline = 'dir f:'

create table #temp (SomeCol varchar(500))


insert #temp
EXEC @ReturnCode = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmdline

if @ReturnCode <> 0
select * from #temp
where SomeCol is not null
```

but of course if you do DIR C: the table will be filled with all the files and folders from that command

Comment: With this technique I was able to suppress any output from the call to xp_cmdshell. 
I had the problem that I always got a result set with a column called output and one row that just contained null - regardless if the call succeeded or failed. Now I use the #temp table as black hole: insert into it, but never select from it, since I just don't care for the output. Thanks again!